# Ломается верстка только в Google Chrome. Как исправить?

Tags: вёрстка, css

[Ломается верхнее меню](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua) (ссылка Контакты съезжает на второю строчку), только в браузере Google Chrome 38.0. В IE11, Mozilla Firefox 32 и браузере Mail.ru (webkit, тотже Chrome) все ОК. Почему так происходит? Как можно исправить только для Хрома?

[image]

В других браузерах:

[image]

Comment: Задай фиксированную ширину для этого блока :)

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, дело в том, что разные браузеры рендерят буковки по-разному. И еще в том, что нарисовано "впритык".

Решение на скорую руку - это проставить **white-space: nowrap**, если айтемы меню вы задаете инлайнами или инлайн-блоками. Если делаете обтеканием, то переделайте на инлайн-блоки. Это запретит переносы строк. Но решения такого рода называются костылями.

Проблема на самом деле глубже, чем кажется. Вам сначала надо решить, что делать в общем случае, когда компонентам нехватает ширины. Скорее всего, нужно уменьшать оступы между компонентами. Тогда вам нужно сделать так, чтобы свободное пространство между айтемами распространялось поровну. И менюшка должна быть реализована, внимание, либо на инлайн-блоках, раскиданных с помощью **text-align: justify**, либо на флексах с **justify-content: space-around**.